# What is wrong with this .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, html5boilerplate, server-error

This .htaccess has been generated by a crontab; I would incidentally like to specify access + 1 week. But the .htaccess I have is:

```
<FilesMatch "(./|\.(html|js))$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
Header set Expires "Sat, 01 Dec 2012 02:34:43 UTC"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(\.css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
Header set Expires "Mon, 24 Dec 2012 02:34:43 UTC"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
Header set Expires "Sun, 24 Nov 2013 02:34:43 UTC"
</FilesMatch>
```

The file is /home/jonathan/.htaccess, and the Apache2 error log states:

[Sat Nov 24 14:03:46 2012] [alert] [client 66.249.75.28] /home/jonathan/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Sat Nov 24 14:03:46 2012] [alert] [client 66.249.75.28] /home/jonathan/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

How can I change this .htaccess so that ideally it is static specifying one week or one month or whatever for different extensions, and at any rate set so it does not generate a server error (500) wen someone tries to use it? The gripe about Header looks like secondary damage; this occurred when I migrated to H5BP.

Comment: It seems that the mod_headers is not included on your Apache server.

Comment: @SubRed +1; thank you. I'm still scratching my head over why this would start to have trouble when I changed static HTML documents. The site in question is http://JonathansCorner.com/ - there might be some good writing but the frontend aspects are hardly pushing the envelope of what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Headers` you can try `Expires` directive like this:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
...
...
```

PS: This will require you have `mod_expires` enabled in your `httpd.conf`